# Business Objects: Finding and displaying the 2nd datetime stamp

Tags: business-objects

I'm struggling to get my head around a calculation in a Business Objects 4.2 webi report that a colleague and I are trying to create.

The report relates to a ChangeLog from our service management system and looks at the amounts of times a ticket has been opened & closed.

In our data provider query, for each ticket there are multiple rows being returned from the universe where the beginning of the text string in object [Change Log(s) Event Details] is 'Status Changed to Open' or 'Status Changed to Closed'. An object called [Change Log(s) Event Date And Time] holds the datetime stamp of the log event.

The desired report structure is a table where the fields are [Company Name], [Incident No], [1st Closure], [2nd Closure], plus more fields to be added later. Something like this:

```
Company Name  | Incident No |    1st Closure      |    2nd Closure       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A N Other Plc | FLT01234567 | 18/04/2017 11:11:08 |  21/04/2017 10:30:05 |
```

[Company Name] and [Incident No] are objects in the universe so we have just referenced those objects directly in the report.

[1st Closure] is working fine using a calculation that returns Min([Change Log(s) Event Date And Time]) value for the incident.

[2nd Closure] is where we are stuck! I've read a few articles on the subject of applying context in report calculations but can't seem to get it quite right.
I feel like we are close with the below calculation but it is currently returning a #MULTIVALUE error. The 'Avoid Duplicate Row Aggregation' option is currently disabled in the Format Table dialog, in case that matters.

```
=[Change Log(s) Event Date And Time] Where((Left([Change Log(s) Event 
Details];20)="Status set to Closed") And Rank([Change Log(s) Event Date And 
Time];Bottom)=2)
```

Can anyone help with a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some way to do this with in the query or report. However, If you have control over the universe you could create a derived table that looks something like this...

```
SELECT a1.CompanyName, a1.IncidentNo, a1.FirstClosure, b1.SecondClosure
FROM
    (
        SELECT CompanyName, IncidentNo, MIN(dtLastChangeLogDateTimeAttempt) AS 'FirstClosure'
        FROM ChangeLog
        GROUP BY CompanyName, IncidentNo
    ) a1
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT b.CompanyName, b.IncidentNo, MIN(a.dtLastChangeLogDateTimeAttempt) AS 'SecondClosure'
        FROM ChangeLog a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT CompanyName, IncidentNo, MIN(dtLastChangeLogDateTimeAttempt) AS 'FirstClosure'
                FROM ChangeLog
                GROUP BY CompanyName, IncidentNo
            ) b ON a.CompanyName = b.CompanyName AND a.IncidentNo AND b.IncidentNo AND a.dtLastChangeLogDateTimeAttempt > b.FirstClosure
        GROUP BY b.CompanyName, b.IncidentNo
    ) b1 ON a1.CompanyName = b1.CompanyName AND a1.IncidentNo AND b1.IncidentNo
```

Noel